# Custom scroll behaviour?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-hooks, use-effect

Currently trying to lock scroll position after a single scroll for one second while I scroll down one section at a time. But I am having some unexpected behaviour.

```
 const [nextSection, setNextSection] = useState('portfolio')

  const [isScrollLocked, setIsScrollLocked] = useState(false)

  const handleScroll = (section) => {
    if (!isScrollLocked) {
      console.log('ran', section)

      setIsScrollLocked(true)
      document.getElementById(section).scrollIntoView()
      document.querySelector('body').classList.add('overflow-hidden')

      setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('overflow-hidden')
        setIsScrollLocked(false)
      }, 1000)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', () => handleScroll(nextSection))
  }, [nextSection])
```

Based on the code above I would think the conditional statement inside handleScroll could only run every second since I change it right away and then only change it back after the settimout but I get a lot of console logs with each scroll. I am updating the nextSection with a scroll spy and parsing it in but despite it being a dependency it does not always seem to update inside the event listener.

Comment: `handleScroll` should probably be defined using a `useCallback`

Comment: You are adding a new event listener whenever `nextSection` changes. If a `useEffect` attaches any kind of listener or subscribes to something it should return a function that also detaches/unsubscribes. And personally I think that blocking scrolling probably leads to a bad user experience. I would be very irritated when I can't scroll while there is a scroll bar indicating that it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Because you added `nextSection` to your dependency list in your effect it will be called whenever `nextSection` changes and attach an additional handler to the `scroll` event. If an effect attaches a handler you need to return a function that detaches it again. Otherwise you will see problems like yours or memory leaks when the component unmounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => handleScroll(nextSection);

    document.addEventListener('scroll', handler);

    // cleanup callback, that will be called before the effect runs again
    return () => document.removeEventListener('scroll', handler);
}, [nextSection])
```

Comment: But with this the scroll event would never fire off right? Anyways I changed it so that the remove is before the add but it still seems to run the console.log inside of handleScroll multipe times  despite the fact it should be able to only run every second.

Comment: Why wouldn't it fire off? The callback in only called before the effect runs again. I don't know what you mean with *I changed it so that the remove is before the add*. Note that the effect returns **a function** that calls `document.removeEventListener()`. It doesn't call it directly.

Comment: @meowzart Do you understand that although you are creating a new `handleScroll` on every render having the new value of `isScrollLocked` the handler that is still attached to the `scroll` event doesn't see that change? This is because your effect only runs when `nextSection` changes, not when `handleScroll` changes. You should use a mutable value, e.g. `useRef` to store the current value of `isScrollLocked` instead of state.

Comment: oh my bad I understand now about the cleanup callback. I added isScrollLocked to the dependency list of the useEffect and parse it into the handleScrolland now I am not having any troubles with temporarily stopping the scroll behaviour and I understand why it was not working before!

Comment: I am sorry to ask but I still have some behaviour happening that I don't understand 100%. Is there any chance you could pull the code from github and try running it on your computer? It's just involving this example before. I obviously understand if that is to much to ask and I really appreciate your help so far.

Comment: @meowzart If you create a minimal working example on codesandbox.com I will have a look at it and point you to a fix.

Comment: I will look into that but I think it would be hard to recreate it since it's kind of tied to my entire application. I will let you know if I figure it out though. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: with your help most things seem to be working as I want it to. Only problem is that the callback cleanup inside useEffect makes it so it never finishes scrolling to the section and instead stops in the middle(no idea why) if I remove it or put it in a timeout I will get to the right section but will of course have other issues.